# why the cart is always empty ?? is it because im not using data from api?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, service

cart component
there is to divs one when the cart is empty and one when not
when I run it its always empty!

I erased the content inside the divs
when cart Empty show the div below

```
<div *ngIf="this.items.length == 0">
 
</div>
```

when cart contains items show the div below

```
<div *ngIf="this.items.length != 0" class="container padding-bottom-3x mb-1">
  
</div>
```

cart.component.ts
here are all functions in cart component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {


  items:item[]=[];

  total:number=0;
  public grandTotal!:number;

  clearCart(){
    this.cartService.clearCart();
    this.items = this.cartService.getItems();
  }
  remove(item:item){
    this.cartService.removeItem(item);
    this.items = this.cartService.getItems();
  }

  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {



  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cartService.getProducts().subscribe(res=>{
      this.items=res;
      this.total=this.grandTotal=this.cartService.getTotalPrice();
   })

  }

}
```

cart.service.ts
here are all functions in cart service:

```
export class CartService {
 cartItems:item[]=[];
 public productList=new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

 addToCart(item: item) {
  this.cartItems.push(item);
  this.productList.next(this.cartItems);
  this.getTotalPrice();
}
getTotalPrice():number{
  let grandTotal=0;
  this.cartItems.map((a:item)=>{
    grandTotal+= a.price;
  })
  return grandTotal;
}
getItems() {
  return this.cartItems;
}
clearCart() {
  this.cartItems = [];
  this.productList.next(this.cartItems);
  return this.cartItems;
}
getLength(){
  console.log(this.cartItems.length);
  return this.cartItems.length;
}
removeItem(item:item){
  this.cartItems.splice(this.cartItems.indexOf(item),1);

}
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

why not working?????

Comment: getProducts code?

Comment: Subscribing in ngoninit is not a good idea, because you do work against the change detection. Use the async pipe to subscribe in the template directly. Otherwise you need to he change detection.

Comment: thanks, but I tried and this is not the problem. it seems that the component runs twice, the second time the list in Service is empty ??

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `productList` in the wrong way, when you declare `public` you can access it directly without signature like this.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cartService.productList.subscribe(res => {
      this.items = res;
      this.total = this.grandTotal = this.cartService.getTotalPrice();
    });

    this.cartService.addToCart({item: 'item a'});
    this.cartService.addToCart({item: 'item b'});
    this.cartService.addToCart({item: 'item c'});
    this.cartService.addToCart({item: 'item d'});

  }
```

Result should be show.

```
 <div *ngIf="this.items.length === 4" class="container padding-bottom-3x mb-1">
   Hello I'm here
 </div>
```